# What do the characters starting with '\' and followed by a number e.g '\234' mean?

Tags: c, char, escaping

I have been looking at the source of an app when I came across these characters e.g  `'\233', '\234', '\235'` and when  I print them, I get garbage characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an escape sequence, for octal values. The syntax is `\nnn`.

You can read more about escape sequences in [c](/questions/tagged/c) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape).

Garbage is printed, because 233 in octal is 155 in decimal, 234 is 156 and 235 is 157. They do not represent any ascii character.

Answer (score 5):

`\233` is the character with the octal code 233.

In decimal this is 2×8<sup>2</sup> + 3×8 + 3 = 155

The meaning depends on the characterset being used. Codes beyond 127 are not defined in 7-bit ASCII.

As advertised by DevSolar:
http://rootdirectory.de/chrome/site/encoding.html might be helpful

Answer (score 4):

They are **octal-escape-sequence**s, which are used to represent specific byte values in a character constant or string literal.

**C11, 6.4.4.4 Character constants**:

```
character-constant:
    ' c-char-sequence '
    L' c-char-sequence '
    u' c-char-sequence '
    U' c-char-sequence '

c-char-sequence:
    c-char
    c-char-sequence c-char

c-char:
    any member of the source character set except the single-quote ', backslash \, or new-line character
    escape-sequence

escape-sequence:
    simple-escape-sequence
    octal-escape-sequence
    hexadecimal-escape-sequence
    universal-character-name

octal-escape-sequence:
    \ octal-digit
    \ octal-digit octal-digit
    \ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit
```

An octal escape sequence is defined as a backslash followed by one to three octal digits (0-7).

To avoid getting a following decimal digit interpreted as part of the octal sequence, it is common practice to pad an octal escape sequence with leading zeroes. As opposed to octal *integer constants*, though, a leading zero is *not required*.

**Note that the *semantic* meaning of such an escape sequence depends on the context.** I could write `"Fu\303\237"`, and it could mean `"Fuß"` (in UTF-8) or `"FuÃŸ"` (in CP-1252), depending of what encoding I am assuming the string to be in. What I can *not* do, portably, is writing *either* of those strings in the source directly, because the interpretation of any character not in the *source character set* (i.e., ASCII-7 without dollar, at-sign, and backtick) is *implementation-defined*. While most compilers today can be made to interpret string literals as UTF-8, octal escape sequences are the portable way.

FWIW, there are also *hexadecimal* escape sequences; however they are not as well-defined: They greedily gobble as many "hex digits" as they can get, even beyond what a `char` can hold; so if the next character in the string literal is one of `[0-9a-fA-F]`, you have no way of "terminating" the hex escape before that (1); this is why octal sequences are preferred by some.

(1): As M.M pointed out, you could split your string literal in two (`"\xAB" "CD"`).

---

As for what the various character values *could* stand for, in which encoding, **I recommend a good code table**. [This one](http://rootdirectory.de/chrome/site/encoding.html) I whipped up myself, as I could not find any existing one listing all the information I needed in one page.

Comment: In a string you can "terminate" by using literal concatenation, e.g. `"\xAB" "CD"`

Comment: @M.M: ...which makes it *two*, concatenated, string literals, and doesn't help readability one bit. ;-) But yes, it's a workaround if you insist on the hex escapes. I've made my peace with the octals.

Answer (score 3):

That notation is *octal-escape-sequence* which represents [octal number representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) for a `char` literal (`char` constant).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.4.4, *Character constants*

> The single-quote `'`, the double-quote `"`, the question-mark `?`, the backslash `\`, and
>   arbitrary integer values are representable according to the following table of escape
>   sequences:
>
> - ...
> - octal character `\octal digits`

and, regarding the values,

> The octal digits that follow the backslash in an octal escape sequence are taken to be part
>   of the construction of a single character for an integer character constant or of a single
>   wide character for a wide character constant. The numerical value of the octal integer so
>   formed specifies the value of the desired character or wide character.